# How to add column [distanceInKm] when i use order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a problem becaouse i dont know how i can add kolumn when i use order by in my procedure which sort distance between customer and vehicle
my procedure lokks like :

```
create procedure    [dbo].[p_top5_v2_type2222]
 @IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int  as
 declare @start geography
  SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
select TOP 5 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
GO
```

and my result is
[image]

now i want to add column [distanceInKm]
to see if they are really well sorted
i try

```
create procedure    p_top5_v2_type_distance
 @IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int  as
 declare @start geography
  SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
select TOP 5 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation 
from Vehicle where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 [distanceInKm]  is not null)
order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 [distanceInKm] asc
GO
```

but i have error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure p_top5_v2_type_distance, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'distanceInKm'.
```

can someone explain how i can add column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns that are selected go in the `select`, not the `order by`.  You can then use it in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select TOP 5 idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange,weight, maxSpeed, nameLocation ,
       @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
from Vehicle
where idGroupVehicle = @idGroupVehicle and  
      (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
order by distanceInKm asc
```

Comment: ok i check this but i have error incorrect syntax near  [distanceInKm] i remove [distanceInKm] and now is correct thanks mate

Comment: @Konrad . . . That is really strange.  I didn't think I modified the `where` clause -- clearly not my intention.